# How to generate all possible Torrent info hashes?

Tags: hash, bittorrent, info-hash

How do I generate all possible torrent info hashes? I am looking for an elegant way to do so.
python code would be immensely appreciated, any other langues are cool too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Start with a hash of all `0`
2. Increment by 1.
3. Go to step 2.

This will obviously run for quite awhile, but will generate all possible torrent info hashes.

Comment: how long should my string be?

Comment: @Max - as long necessary to create a torrent